How to update the state for only one component using Zustand?
I'm writing a simple Todo List and I want my tasks to be added and removed from favorites with a single button. Task code:
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { StarOutlined, StarFilled, EditFilled, DeleteFilled } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { useFavoriteStore } from "../assets/ZustandStore";

  function Task (props:any){

  const removeFromFavorite = useFavoriteStore((state) => state.removeFromFavorite)
  const isFavorite = useFavoriteStore((state)=>state.isFavorite)

  return (
    <StyledTask className="margin">
      <TaskTitle className="task-title">
        {props.title}
      </TaskTitle>
        { isFavorite ?
          <StarFilled onClick={props.addToFavorite} style={iconStyle} /> :
          <StarOutlined onClick={() => removeFromFavorite(props.id)} style={iconStyle}/>
        }
    </StyledTask>
  )
}

export default Task

I use the simpliest Zustand code:
import { create } from 'zustand'

type MyFavorites = {
  isFavorite: boolean;
  favorite: any[];
  addToFavorite: (task:any) => void;
  removeFromFavorite: (taskId:any) => void;
  toggleIsFavorite: () => void;
};

export const useFavoriteStore = create<MyFavorites>((set) => ({
  isFavorite: false,
  favorite: [],
  addToFavorite: (task) => set((state) => ({favorite: [...state.favorite, task], isFavorite: !state.isFavorite
  })),
  removeFromFavorite: (taskId) => set((state) => ({favorite: state.favorite.filter(task => task.id !== taskId),
    isFavorite: !state.isFavorite
  })),
  toggleIsFavorite: () => set((state) => ({isFavorite: !state.isFavorite}))
}))

Adding and deleting a task from the favorites is performed correctly. But when I click on a button to change the status of a particular task, of course it changes the buttons on all tasks. I have no idea how to change isFavorite state only for a task that has been added to favorites

Create an array of object instead of one object. Use a unique identifier to target any specific object when updating.
